# Is there a phrase in English for moving your forefinger close to someone's face in a bossy way?

Tags: phrases, expressions

This picture shows clearly what I'm looking for.  Is there a phrase for that?

[image]

In French there is a phrase for it, with the French word for finger, "un doigt remuant" Is there any in BrE and in AmE?

EDIT - For Clarity - The person moves his finger up and down, in a threatening way, as if he wanted to touch the other person's nose. Also, he often moves it rhythmically, as he speaks. The only vídeo clip I found about "finger in the face" **shows what I'm not looking for**. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=peJ2veop1bk

Comment: The French tend to use rather more hand and body gestures generally than do English-speaking people. Finger-wagging is just one. They also perform an exaggerated shrug of the shoulders when indicating uncertainty about anything.

Comment: My response, in English, would be 'get your/that finger out of my face.'  So maybe put your finger in someone's face? It's not a saying  though. And I've not heard of much finger wiggling in AmE.

Comment: I LOVE this question! My mother was notorious for not only pointing her finger in your face, but punctuating each word of admonition with a fingernail to the forehead. In the absence of an "official" idiom, we christened this activity "Patsy (her name)-finger". As in: "Get that "Patsy-finger" out of my face before I bite it off".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One vivid way to describe the act of moving one's forefinger toward the other person's face is "jabbing [one's] finger." A Google search turns up multiple examples of this usage. From Laura Simon, [*Dreams of Paradise*](https://books.google.com/books?id=aE2gaK1cW8wC&q=%22jabbing+his+finger%22&dq=%22jabbing+his+finger%22&hl=en&sa=X&ei=SdaVVKrHN4npoASYhIHwCQ&ved=0CCQQ6AEwAQ) (1991):

> "It's a legitimate business from which I fully expect to realize a profit. I wouldn't have started it otherwise. I would have sent you anonymous envelopes full of money instead. God knows, it would have been easier. Given that fact," he went on, **jabbing his finger** in front of her face, "I can't comprehend why you should find it less objectionable to sell your designs to some cigar-chomping stranger than to me."
>
> Hazel swatted his finger away.

From Diana Dempsey, [*Falling Star*](https://books.google.com/books?id=GodIwzHkCIoC&q=%22jabbing+his+finger%22&dq=%22jabbing+his+finger%22&hl=en&sa=X&ei=0NWVVJrHOM6yogSK94KgDg&ved=0CC8Q6AEwBDgK) (2002) [combined snippets]:

> Then his eyes got all wild and he started screaming and **jabbing his finger** in her face, as if he was going out of control. He looked like a lunatic. But she didn't budge. She just waited for it to be over.

From *Atwater v. City of Lago Vista* (2001), quoted in Andrew Taslitz, [*Reconstructing the Fourth Amendment: A History of Search and Seizure, 1789–1868*](https://books.google.com/books?id=GOpW_DdlMSIC&pg=PA81&dq=%22jabbing+his+finger+in+Atwater%27s+face%22&hl=en&sa=X&ei=wtKVVOLnJJLloATQ8oD4Dw&ved=0CDcQ6AEwBA#v=onepage&q=%22jabbing%20his%20finger%20in%20Atwater%27s%20face%22&f=false) (2006):

> Turek was loud and accusatory from the moment he approached Atwater's car. Atwater's young children were terrified and hysterical. Yet when Atwater asked Turek to lower his voice because he was scaring the children, he responded by **jabbing his finger** in Atwater's face and saying, “You're going to jail.”

From [*Mileikowsky v. Tenet HealthSystem*](http://caselaw.findlaw.com/ca-court-of-appeal/1448002.html), California Court of Appeal, Second District (April 18, 2005):

> The second stated basis for the suspension was a December 1999 incident where Dr. Mileikowsky was informed, during performance of a surgery, that his assistant did not have surgical privileges. Dr. Mileikowsky allegedly backed the operating room manager against a wall while screaming at her and **jabbing his finger** in her face.

From Walter Sorrels, [*Fake ID*](https://books.google.com/books?id=cP_tAAAAMAAJ&q=%22jabbing+his+finger%22&dq=%22jabbing+his+finger%22&hl=en&sa=X&ei=2dSVVNzfGY23oQSexYKYCg&ved=0CCcQ6AEwAjgK) (2005) [combined snippets]:

> Two minutes later I was sitting in his office while he stood over me, **jabbing his finger** in my face. "Where were you yesterday afternoon?" he shouted.

From Jeffrey Feldman, [*Outright Barbarous: How the Violent Language of the Right Poisons American Democracy*](https://books.google.com/books?id=Cs0UAQAAIAAJ&q=%22jabbing+his+finger%22&dq=%22jabbing+his+finger%22&hl=en&sa=X&ei=jc-VVPzIK4LvoAS_tICoCQ&ved=0CB8Q6AEwAA) (2008) [combined snippets]:

> In this case, the exclamation points in the transcript indicate moments where O'Reilly barked loudly and **jabbed his finger** towards Rivera's face. In fact, a video clip of O'Reilly shouting and **jabbing his finger** at a stunned Rivera circulated on the Internet and was discussed on political talk shows for the next week.

Comment: Thanks for the answer.  Somehow I missed it at the time it was posted.

Answer (score 8):

This gesture is known as **wagging** (or **shaking**) **one's finger** at someone.

Someone using the most aggressive form of the gesture could be said to be **wagging their finger in the other person's face**.

See [here](https://www.google.com/search?safe=off&rlz=1C1CHFX_enUS577US577&es_sm=122&biw=1846&bih=952&tbm=isch&sa=1&q=%22wagging+his+finger%22&oq=%22wagging+his+finger%22&gs_l=img.3...10123.10350.0.10583.2.2.0.0.0.0.86.165.2.2.0.msedr...0...1c.1.60.img..2.0.0.fvVubk0WNhI) for the results of a Google Images search for "wagging his finger".

Comment: To use it as a noun, could you say "he showed me a wagging finger"?

Comment: @Centaurus - Someone could say that, and it would not exactly be *wrong*; but it would sound peculiar to a native speaker, even though they would probably understand what was meant.

Comment: Kindly use italic for mentions, not bold.

Comment: I have to disagree because this looks more like finger pointing rather than wagging. I understand finger wagging as holding the extended index finger vertical and moving it side to side like a metronome usually accompanied with a few tuts. A typical UK response to the guy in the picture would be; _'Don't point your bloody finger at me!'_

Comment: I disagree with @JoeDark I would call this shaking or wagging, not pointing.

Comment: @ColinFine From the picture it's impossible to tell if he's actually wagging his finger either up or down or side to side. He might just be holding his hand still and is therefore pointing.

Comment: @JoeDark - The OP is clearly at fault for not providing a video clip which incontrovertibly shows a finger being wagged (preferably with close-ups), having the cheek to merely *imply* it in the title of the question. (The  ***nerve*** of some people!)

Comment: @Centaurus - I don't think anyone would know what you meant if you said "he showed me a wagging finger". That isn't a common expression so it could be interpreted many ways.

Comment: @ErikKowal I'm not sure you really mean I should have provided a vídeo clip or if it was only a sarcastic remark (The nerve...) Anyways, the only vídeo I could find is this, and it shows the kind of movement I DO NOT MEAN.  https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=peJ2veop1bk

Comment: @Centaurus - I was making a sarcastic comment about what seemed to me to be Joe Dark attempting to read more into your photo than I thought was justified. But thanks for the link.

Answer (score 1):

*Finger-pointing* is a noun which means, according to Merriam-Webster,

```
the act of blaming someone for a problem instead of trying to fix or solve it
```

It seems that its literal way of interpretation, that of really pointing your finger towards somebody, is not very obvious.

Probably not the best phrase you want. To me, finger-pointing lacks the heat connoted in your picture.

Answer (score 1):

In AmE, we might say *putting your finger in my face* or more commonly *take your finger out of my face*. I cannot answer for what our special friends across the pond say, but I'm sure it's quite interesting whatever it is.

[See google images search for plenty.](https://www.google.co.jp/search?q=finger%20in%20face&es_sm=91&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ei=DMuVVOjbNIieyASCp4GoAw&ved=0CAgQ_AUoAQ&biw=1264&bih=604)

Answer (score 0):

You could call it "pointing an 'accusatory finger'", but you'd still have to specify that it was in someone's face.

Answer (score 0):

The phrase [**power wagging**](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HBbKC7RG9_4) is close, although power wagging does not necessarily require that the finger be moved rhythmically or in somebody's face.

Comment: Do you have a more reliable citation for that than some random TV show? For all we know, that show just invented the term for humorous effect and nobody else uses it.

Comment: @DavidRicherby Sorry, the only other usages I know of are anecdotal, which really aren't worth mentioning. It's quite possible that TV show did invent it.